# Change Textbox object to Static

Tags: c#, textbox

I have little experience in C#, mostly playing with it as a hobby, and I was wondering what I needed to do to change a textbox from non-static to static.

In Visual Studio 2012, I'm trying to add a line of text using the method `textbox1.AppendText("Text");`, and it won't work because the textbox isn't static, while the method trying to write the code is static. I can't find the line of code where the textbox is initialized in my code, nor have I found an option in the properties that allows me to change that.

Is there a work-around, or do I need to make it static? And if I need to make it static, how would I do that? I'm at a loss.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: adding code sample. The method below is called from a second form, same from which the value of x is determined.

```
public static void getMethod(int x)
{
    if (x > 4)
    {
        textbox1.AppendText("Text");
    }
    else
    {
        textbox1.AppendText("Other text");
        otherVariable = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did yo try this??  textbox1.text = textbox1.text + "WhatEverYouNeedToShow";

Comment: make your method non-static

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your post which GUI framework you're using. Both Winforms and WPF have a `TextBox` class.

But, to the point of your question: you could in the object where the `TextBox` is declared and created, also have a static field to which you assign that reference. But that would be a poor design choice, IMHO.

It's not clear what your static code is doing, where it's declared, or who called it (another failing of your question is that you did not provide any code, never mind [a concise, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but assuming the static method is not in the UI object that owns the `TextBox` instance itself (if it is, then you just need to make the method non-static), the the correct way to address this would be for the UI object that does know about the `TextBox` instance to have some public method or property used to set the text, and then for the code that invokes your static method to pass the reference of that UI object to the static method, so that it can use the member you added.

For example:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    public string FieldText
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

and elsewhere:

```
static void SomeMethod(Form1 form)
{
    // ...do some stuff...

    form.FieldText = "some text";

    // ...do some other stuff...
}
```

In your specific scenario, you seem to have two forms: one containing the `textbox1` member, and another that passes an `int` value to a method, where you want to be able to add some text to the `TextBox1` based on the value.

In that case, it would look more like this:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    public void AppendFieldText(string text)
    {
        textbox1.AppendText(text);
    }
}
```

and in the `static` method:

```
public static void getMethod(int x, Form1 form)
{
    if (x > 4)
    {
        form.AppendFieldText("Text");
    }
    else
    {
        form.AppendFieldText("Other text");
        otherVariable = x;
    }
}
```

Naturally, the caller of the `getMethod()` method will need the reference for the `form` parameter; you will have to pass that somehow to that second form which is calling this method, so that it can pass it to the method.

Note that in both of my examples, I have not exposed the `TextBox` object itself. You should follow this example, exposing only the minimum amount of functionality needed in order to get the job done. This helps ensure that the `TextBox` object doesn't wind up getting used in appropriately by some other code, and especially helps ensure that your classes remain reasonably decoupled.

On that latter point, I will mention that your code example is still pretty bare. There are other techniques which can solve this problem with even less coupling between the types. But again, lacking a good code example, it's not possible to know for sure what would work, never mind what would be best.

The above example is appropriate, given the information you've shared.

If you would like to edit your question to provide better, more specific detail, a better, more specific answer could be provided.

Comment: I've updated my post by including sample code. If you need anything else, let me know. Sorry again for the lack of code.

Comment: @FredJ: please see my added detail

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getMethod(textBox1,5);
    }


    public static void getMethod(TextBox textbox1,int x)
    {
        if (x > 4)
        {
            textbox1.AppendText("Text");
        }
        else
        {
            textbox1.AppendText("Other text");
            otherVariable = x;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Textboxes aren't static. And you can't make them static, they are all instanciated. The name of your textbox is the instance name.

So just use the text property on the instance of the text box.

```
textbox1.Text = "Text";
```

If you want to Append one just do:

```
textbox1.Text = String.Concat(Textbox1.Text, "more text");
```

same thing about could also be seen as:

```
textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text + "more text";
```